# Linq2Sql how to get all distinct dates without time part

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2005 express
I have a datetime field in a table witch contains date and time.

I want to select distinct the dates from the table ignoring the time part.

I used this code but the order by is ignored ! (the generated sql doesn't contain order by) :

```
        var dates = (from c in db.Comments
                     orderby c.Time descending
                     select c.Time.Day + "/" + c.Time.Month + "/" + c.Time.Year).Distinct();
```

Any ideas on how to do this are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type.

```
var dates = from c in db.Comments
             group c by c.Time.Date into g
             orderby g.Key
             select g.Key;
```

or

```
var dates = (from c in db.Comments
            select c.Time.Date).Distinct().OrderBy(d => d);
```

An SQL expert can tell you which of these is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var comments = from c in db.Comments
               select c.Time.Day + "/" + c.Time.Month + "/" + c.Time.Year).Distinct();

comments = comments.OrderBy(c => c.Time);
```

Answer (score 2):

> order by is ignored!

Yes, you are instructing linq to order, and then to distinct.  Distinct in linq is an operation that destroys ordering.  You must orderby after the distinct:

```
query = query.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Also, it is profane to use string manipulation to perform date logic.  You should project using the Date property of DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which lets you see the generated SQL. Play with different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure the [Time] column won't be NULL I can't see any problems with this idea and it's easier for we "humans" to read:

```
 var dates = (from c in db.Comments
             orderby c.Time.Year, c.Time.Month, c.Time.Day
             select c.Time.Day + "/" + c.Time.Month + "/" + c.Time.Year).Distinct();
```

Or in reverse-chronological sort-order:

```
 var dates = (from c in db.Comments
             orderby c.Time.Year descending, c.Time.Month descending, c.Time.Day descending
             select c.Time.Day + "/" + c.Time.Month + "/" + c.Time.Year).Distinct();
```